# huggingface wav2vec-base model -- hours of fine-tuning?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I'm using the pre-trained "facebook/wav2vec2-base" model from huggingface to fine-tune wav2vec on a  a new task/with a new dataset. I was wondering, for this model, how much labeled data was it fine-tuned on (if any)? I need the information to report in a paper.

According to this: [https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/blob/main/examples/wav2vec/README.md](https://stackoverflow.com) , wav2vec-base had NO fine-tuning on labeled data, but according to the actual wav2vec paper: [https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11477.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com), there were no wav2vec models reported that weren't trained on labeled data.

Does anyone know the pre-training/fine-tuning details of "wav2vec-base"? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.